# html input displays different text to value that it posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter, input

I am feeling really stupid and not sure if doing something really dumb what... so excuse me in advance.

I have the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="0" name="pcscubes" id="pcscubes">
```

I have the below jquery syntax:

```
var cubes=123.2;
$("#pcscubes1").val(cubes);
var test=$("#pcscubes1").val();
alert(test);
```

When the jquery executes, the input box will display 123.2 and the alert will be 123.2.

if you inspect the html object though, the value is still 0?

so the display of the input is different from what the real value is. so when I submit this form it posts 0 rather than 123.2

Now I have built a whole web app with this syntax and works perfectly. today it just stops working? I have restarted browser, checked old code that was working, logged off and on and still it does the same.

web app obviously has jquery loaded and jquery ui on this form.

using codeigniter?

any ideas as I am banging my head over something so stupid....

Out of interest I created the below fiddle and it is doing the same?
http://jsfiddle.net/49nqU/

[image]

why is the value 0 when it is showing 123.2?

Thanks as always,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a case of attributes vs. properties.

What you are seeing in the inspector is the `value` **attribute**, which does not update when you programmatically update a field's `value` **property.**

Pay no attention to what the DOM inspector says; it'll only show the value as it was when the page loaded (unless you explicitly change the field's value **attribute** rather than, as jQuery's `val()` does, its `value` **property**.)

Further reading: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/html-difference-between-attribute-and.html

Some attributes are closely tied to their property counterparts. That is to say, updating the property also updates the attribute. This is the case, for example, with the `class` attribute and its `className` property counterpart. `value`, however, is different; updating the property does not update the attribute (but, just to confuse things further, updating the attribute *does* update the property!)

Comment: To clarify a little bit, the value **attribute** is the _default value_ of the input, not the _current value_.

Answer (score 3):

`val()` is changing the value property, not attribute. The value attribute is initialized at the loading of the page. Once you change text field the value property and attribute have differnet values.

But you can use plain JS for changing the value attribute also.

Try:

```
var cubes=123.2;
document.getElementById('qty').setAttribute('value',cubes);
var test=$("#qty").val();
alert(test);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/49nqU/1/)

Comment: Since value is a property, you should set the `value` property, using `setAttribute` is not the proper way of manipulating properties.

Comment: @undefined I am using `setAttribute` for changing the value attribute as the OP wants. By changing that as a side effect you have also the change of value property